# calculating required deceleration for known velocity and distance

Tags: calculus, physics

I want to apologize if you think my question is a duplicate but honestly I could not understand the answer I found in this [**question**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373463/how-do-i-create-an-equation-that-decelerates-past-a-certain-value), nor any other answer I found on from searching.

I have a robot that should start decelerating when it's ultrasonic sensor starts giving values below `70` (assuming it's cm), this deceleration should continue until it reaches `35 cm`. my initial velocity is a variable but for now we could assume it is `48.8793 cm/s`. I want to be able calculate required amount of deceleration so when I reach `35 cm` I know for sure my velocity is `23 cm/s`.

Again I'm sorry if my question is a duplicate I've been just confusing myself for the past couple of days, also my tags might be referring to unrelated areas? would appreciate any help.

Thank you

/y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do the calculation, describing in some detail the reasoning.

Let the velocity when the sensor reads $70$ cm be $v_0\gt 23$.

We will apply a *constant* acceleration $-a$ (the minus sign is because we are decelerating).

Let $t$ be the amount of time we take to get from sensor says $70$  to sensor says $35$.

The end-velocity is $23$.

We have 
$$at=v_0-23.\tag{1}$$
For the acceleration times elapsed time is the change in velocity.

The **average** velocity from the time we start decelerating to the end is $\dfrac{v_0+23}{2}$. At this average velocity, we travelled a net distance of $70-35=35$ in time $t$. Thus
$$35=\frac{v_0+23}{2}{t}.\tag{2}$$
We want to use Equations 1 and 2 to eliminate $t$. Using the two equations, we get
$$t=\frac{v_0-23}{a}=\frac{70}{v_0+23}.$$
This can be rewritten as
$$a=\frac{v_0-23}{70(v_0+23)}.$$

Comment: You're a life saver, very simple and clear answer thank you mr. Nicolas

Comment: Note that this will also provide the same deceleration rate and potential sharpness as the method I described, but with equations to support your efforts.

Comment: ah okay, I guess I miss understood your answer :(

Thanks for your help both

Answer (score 1):

Consider a constant deceleration rate:  then the average of the starting and ending speeds is the average speed across the deceleration span, and if you divide the deceleration distance by this average speed, you get the total deceleration time.  Then divide the average speed by this amount of time and you get the necessary deceleration rate.

Comment: but wouldn't that be a sharp deceleration pattern? thanks for answering

Comment: I'm not sure about sharp...  Changing to a constant deceleration from none would probably have a high rate of jerk, but otherwise will provide a very smooth speed transition.